# Columns of Virtual Desktops in Openbox

Tags: arch-linux, openbox

I'm setting up Openbox in Arch and was trying to setup the virtual desktops like I usually like them, in one tall column.  The default is to have them setup as a single row and the Openbox config utility only has the ability to add to that.

Is there a way to have Openbox use virtual columns of virtual desktops?

Comment: If you check out ~/.config/openbox/rc.xml , you'll find it's not likely to be supported , so send a feature request to the author.

Comment: Related:  https://superuser.com/q/347528/607821

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check this out http://openbox.org/dist/tools/setlayout.c
Remember to compile with -lX11